# How do I get notified whenever a new editor is opened in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have a view which would like to be notified about all the currently opened editors. Where can I add a listener to achieve this?

I was expecting WorkbenchPage or EditorManager to have some appropriate listener registry, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does your view uses a [`org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener2`](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPartListener2.html) ?

That is what is using this [EditorListener](http://www.koders.com/java/fidC16A4CE2FC6A7F818AD035376967CA06F87DBA4F.aspx?s=EditorListener+IPartListener2#L27), whose job is to react, for a given view, to Editor events (including open and close)

```java
public class EditorListener implements ISelectionListener, IFileBufferListener,
IPartListener2 {
    protected BytecodeOutlineView view;

    EditorListener(BytecodeOutlineView view){
        this.view = view;
    }

[...] 

    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener2#partOpened(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPartReference)
     */
    public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
        view.handlePartVisible(partRef.getPart(false));
    }
```

---

Now if your `ViewPart` directly implements an `IPartListener2`, it can register itself to the various `Editors`, like this [`BytecodeReferenceView`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid44B9CA94742C6FE34142932F9531FB5E438F338E.aspx?s=EditorListener+IPartListener2)

```java
public class BytecodeReferenceView extends ViewPart implements IPartListener2, ISelectionListener {

    [...]

    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        browser.setText(BytecodeOutlinePlugin.getResourceString(NLS_PREFIX
            + "empty.selection.text"));
        final IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = getSite().getWorkbenchWindow();
        workbenchWindow.getPartService().addPartListener(this);
    [...]
```

Comment: do you have an example how I can add this EditorListener to the default Java code editor in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track. You need to listen to the IWorkbenchPage [IPartService](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/documentation/2.0/html/plugins/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPartService.html) events:

```
page.addPartListener(new IPartListener() {
    partOpened(IWorkbenchPart part) {
        ...
    }

    ...
});
```

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything for me

Comment: ah... I was not reading your comment properly. I had added it to the page, not to the page's partService.

Comment: You probably didn't misread it - I thought you could just listen to the page directly. Apparently not.