# Listener on open file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, api, listener

I am currently working on a Eclipse Plugin, where I need to make an action, when a person opens a file with certain properties. However I'm not sure on how to set a listener, I have been looking into the `IWorkspace` and `IResource` API, but I can't find the simple API call saying "AddListenerToOnOpenFile".

The file is expected to be opened in the package explorer view.

Comment: [How do I get notified whenever a new editor is opened in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/542338/150166).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the answer supplied by @MarttiKäärik to find out when editors are open.  Then you can use the IEditorInput to see if it is an IResource you care about.

```
if (part instanceof IEditorPart) {
    IEditorPart editor = (IEditorPart) part;
    IResource resource = editor.getEditorInput().getAdapter(IResource.class);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Question already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786918/listener-on-open-file-in-eclipse/8791151#8791151), so only to make it a bit more complete...

You don't necessarily have to implement a view or action (as described in [the question linked to by Martti Käärik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542338/how-do-i-get-notified-whenever-a-new-editor-is-opened-in-eclipse) in a comment) to get a window for your listener. Call to `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().get...()` can be used as well. See the older, probably duplicate, question called just [Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030682/eclipse-plugin).

BTW [Eclipse Wiki FAQ page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_the_active_workbench_page%3F) contains a good description of the ways how to obtain the current workbench window and possible "gotchas".

Moreover, you can even listen for newly opened windows if there is a need:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().addWindowListener(listener);
```